# bash regular expression format

Tags: regex, bash

My code have problem with compare var with regular expression.

The main problem is problem is here

```
if [[ “$alarm” =~ ^[0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]$ ]]
```

This "if" is never true i dont know why even if i pass to "$alarm" value like 13:00  or 08:19 its always false and write "invalid clock format".

When i try this ^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ on site to test regular expressions its work for example i compered with 12:20.

I start my script whith command ./alarm 11:12
below is whole code

```
#!/bin/bash
masa="`date +%k:%M`"
mp3="$HOME/Desktop/alarm.mp3" #change this
echo "lol";
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
 echo "please insert alarm time [24hours format]"
 echo "example ./alarm 13:00 [will ring alarm at 1:00pm]"
exit;
fi

alarm=$1
echo "$alarm"
#fix me with better regex >_<
if [[ “$alarm” =~ ^[0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]$ ]]
then
 echo "time now $masa"
 echo "alarm set to $alarm"
 echo "will play $mp3"
else
 echo "invalid clock format"
exit;
fi

while [ $masa != $alarm ];do
 masa="`date +%k:%M`" #update time
 sleep 1 #dont overload the cpu cycle
done

echo $masa
if [ $masa = $alarm ];then
 echo ringggggggg
 play $mp3 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
fi
exit
```

Comment: Your question uses smart quotes around `$alarm`; are those actually in your code, or is that a typo in your question? They would be ignored by the shell and treated as part of the value being matched against the regular expression, which looks fine, if overly permissive (it allows times like `25:00`). You don't need to escape the `:`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues with your test.

Firstly, it looks like you may be using the wrong kind of double quotes around your variable (`“` `”`, rather than `"`). These "fancy quotes" are being concatenated with your variable, which I assume is what causes your pattern to fail to match. You could change them but within bash's extended tests (i.e. `[[` instead of `[`), there's no need to quote your variables anyway, so I would suggest removing them entirely.

Secondly, your regular expression allows some invalid dates at the moment. I would suggest using something like this:

```
re='^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'
if [[ $alarm =~ $re ]]
```

I have deliberately chosen to use a separate variable to store the pattern, as this is the most widely compatible way of working with bash regexes.